# stm32l476 HAl GPIO Init sends program counter to position 0000 0000

Tags: c, initialization, stm32, gpio, hal

I've been some months working on a Firmware for STM32L476VG. I've made a second version of my PCB adding more hardware as 6 MOSFET controlled from MCU.

The problem is with the MOSFET controlled from PE10, as seen in the code below when I put the declarations and initialization which is correct or that’s what I think because I’ve been using same type of declarations and initializations in more projects, then the running/debug has strange behavior. It goes thru the code until it finds:
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);
Here sometimes jumps to memory position 0000 0000,
Other it gets stuck at startup_stm32l476xxx.s LoopForever(line 118)  here it gets because strange or unexpected ISR, I have to investigate more about this.

If comment  lines

```
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_10,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_10;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_OD;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);
```

All runs perfect, except PE10

```
void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

    /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();


    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_10,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_10;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_OD;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_9,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_11,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_11;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_12,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_12;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_11,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_11;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_1,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_1;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;    
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}
```

Debugging in step by step mode I'm unable to recreate the error i go thru all the HAL and GPIO libraries and I'm able to continue with normal program.

What is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Code looks correct.  I noticed that you configured this output differently than the others.  (Open Drain) and speed is different as well.  I would look at the hardware that was added. You might want to add some delay after you put the GPIO in reset before calling HAL_GPIO_Init to simulate what the could be happening by using the debugger.  Maybe the hardware needs some time to settle after you put the IO in reset? If you shared the schematic that might help.

Comment: Sounds like you might be browning out. Otherwise you might have some other fault like a hard fault, bus fault etc as these do not always show up when single step debugging.

Comment: dernst: yes, is diferent because I was doing many changes of all parametres and those are the ones left when I wrote the wuestion, with other velocities, pull up and pull down,... the error was the same.

Comment: Realtime Rik: I have put waits long as 100 ms and the problem stills there. With wirerap I have connected PE10 to PE8 and PE8 don't gives any problem. For now I will work with PE8, and when the second board is mounted i will see if it is a systematic error or a MCU error

Comment: In the second PCB, the code works fine. So must be a problem with the chip. I would mark as correct answer when I have tried more boards to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

After mounting 10 PCBs there is only one with this issue, so I will answer it was a problem with the MCU